# How to determine the decimal value to which two or more values in an unknown base are equal to.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Lets say I have 200 with an unknown base and 1212 also in an unknown base but I'm told these numbers in base 10 are equal. How do I find that base 10 value.

Comment: So, you are looking for positive integer solutions to the diophantine equation $2x^2 = y^3+2y^2+y+2$?

Comment: We just had a question about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388572/determining-base-of-a-number).

Comment: That said, it looks like the solution isn't unique... $200_5 = 1212_3 = 50_{10}$ while also $200_{15}=1212_7=450_{10}$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes the solution isn't unique. but any of the base ten answers is okay. So how do you derive to any of them. Is there an equation or something.